# numpy array partial sums with weights

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, slice

I have a numpy array, say, `[a,b,c,d,e,...]`, and would like to compute an array that would look like `[x*a+y*b, x*b+y*c, x*c+y*d,...]`. The idea that I have is to first split the original array into something like `[[a,b],[b,c],[c,d],[d,e],...]` and then attack this creature with `np.average` specifying the axis and weights (`x+y=1` in my case), or even use `np.dot`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to create such array of `[a,b],[b,c],...` pairs. Any help, or completely different idea even to accomplish the major task, are much appreciated :-)

Comment: I think this nested generator works: `[(v1*x + v2*y) for v1, v2 in [arr[i:i+2] for i in xrange(len(arr)-1)]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest, simplest would be to manually extract two slices of your array and add them together:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(5)
>>> x, y = 10, 1
>>> x*arr[:-1] + y*arr[1:]
array([ 1, 12, 23, 34])
```

This will turn into a pain if you want to generalize it to triples, quadruples... But you can create your array of pairs from the original array with `as_strided` in a much more general form:

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

>>> arr_pairs = as_strided(arr, shape=(len(arr)-2+1,2), strides=arr.strides*2)
>>> arr_pairs
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

Of course the nice thing about using `as_strided` is that, just like with the array slices, there is no data copying involved, just messing with the way memory is viewed, so creating this array is virtually costless.

And now probably the fastest is to use `np.dot`:

```
>>> xy = [x, y]
>>> np.dot(arr_pairs, xy)
array([ 1, 12, 23, 34])
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a [correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) problem.

```
a
Out[61]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

b
Out[62]: array([1, 2])

np.correlate(a,b,mode='valid')
Out[63]: array([ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14, 17, 20])
```

Depending on array size and BLAS dot can be faster, your milage will vary greatly:

```
arr = np.random.rand(1E6)

b = np.random.rand(2)

np.allclose(jamie_dot(arr,b),np.convolve(arr,b[::-1],mode='valid'))
True

%timeit jamie_dot(arr,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

%timeit np.correlate(arr,b,mode='valid')
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop
```

This is with an intel mkl BLAS and 8 cores, `np.correlate` will likely be faster for most implementations.

Also an interesting observation from @Jamie's post:

```
%timeit b[0]*arr[:-1] + b[1]*arr[1:]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.43 ms per loop
```

His comment also eliminated the use of `np.convolve(a,b[::-1],mode=valid)` to the simpler `correlate` syntax.

Comment: It's actually more of a [`correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) problem, but yes, +1. Actually, if you look at [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L873) `np.convolve(a, b)` calls `np.correlate(a, b[::-1])`.

Comment: @Jamie Oh neat, I never noticed that function- its good to know you can do this sort of thing without convolve trickery.

Comment: @Ophion, neat, very insightful!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small array, I would create a shifted copy:

```
shifted_array=numpy.append(original_array[1:],0)
result_array=x*original_array+y*shifted_array
```

Here you have to store your array twice in memory, so this solution is very memory inefficient, but you can get rid of the for loops.

If you have large arrays, you really need a loop (but much rather a list comprehension):

```
result_array=[x*original_array[i]+y*original_array[i+1] for i in xrange(len(original_array)-1)]
```

It gives you the same result as a python list, except for the last item, which should be treated differently anyway.

Based on some random trials, for arrays smaller than 2000 items. the first solution seems to be faster than the second one, but runs into MemoryError even for relatively small arrays (a few 10s of thousands on my PC).

So generally, use a list comprehension, but if you surely know that you will run this only on small (max. 1-2 thousand) arrays, you have a better shot.

Creating a new list like `[[a,b],[b,c],[c,d],[d,e],...]` would be both memory and time inefficient, as you also need a for loop (or similar) to create it, and you have to store every old value in a new array twice, so you would end up with storing your original array three times.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create the right pairs in the array `a = np.array([a,b,c,d,e,...])`, reshape according to the size of array `b = np.array([x, y, ...])` and then take advantage of `numpy` broadcasting rules:

```
a = np.arange(8) 
b = np.array([1, 2])

a = a.repeat(2)[1:-1]
ans = a.reshape(-1, b.shape[0]).dot(b)
```

Timings (on my computer):

```
@Ophion's solution:
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.67 µs per loop

This solution:
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.78 µs per loop
```

So, it is slower. @Jaime's solution is better since it does not copy the data like this one.